# Lawn tractor blue white smoke

Tags: smoke, lawnmower

I was mowing for the first time this season and after an hour, I noticed a small amount of smoke, liquid spray from near the carburetor area. 
I noticed a hose had popped out so I reconnected it. This hose connects the engine block to air intake tube and I believe it is called a breather tube. This hose has a part inside that looks like a plug with a small hole.

I checked the oil level and since it was low, I added a bit to just below full. I restarted it and that’s when it started blowing blue white smoke out of the exhaust. I checked the oil dipstick and it smells like gas.

Mower is a Sears 46” 21 hp B&S. 10+ years old.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix would be most appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like the carb float may be stuck and allowing too much fuel in. Sort of a "flooding" state. You might try tapping on the float bowl a little bit, but probably the needle/seat valve isn't working correctly (sealing) or the float itself isn't floating.